# Sharepoint custom list with multiple content types, why the fileds will not be changed if we change the content type choice

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I  have a SharePoint custom list >> which contain 3 content types (items, Form1 & Form2). Now when I created a Power App canvas >> define a form >> define the custom list as the data source for the list >> I will get all the fields >> and if I add the content type drop-down >>

[image]

I change the content type name >> the fields will not be shown/hidden based on the content type selection. So how can I mimic the same behavior as the built-in SharePoint forms?

Where the fields will get shown/hidden based on the selected content type. Is this possible?

Comment: It will not change fields automatically. You have to set `Visible` property of controls/datacards based on content type drop down selection to show/hide fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using SharePoint list forms in Power apps, fields will not change automatically based on selection of content type.

You have to use custom business logic to show/hide fields in Power Apps in this scenario. You have to set `Visible` property of controls/data cards based on content type drop down selection to show/hide fields.

**Example**:

Consider, name of you content type drop down is: `ddContentType`

And you want to show the text field which is under data card named `DataCardTextInput` only when selected content type name is "Item"

Then you have to set `Visible` property of data card in below format:

```
ddContentType.Selected.Value = "Item"
```

You can adjust controls/datacards and property names as per your requirements.

Check this thread for more information, this will help you to achieve your needs: [SharePoint Content Types in PowerApps Form - A Workaround!](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/SharePoint-Content-Types-in-PowerApps-Form-A-Workaround/td-p/813257)